# data structure to store and manipulate efficienty pixels :

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

l have a set of images (1000 images). each one has a dimension of 3072.
each image has this representation :
image 1 for instance :

```
array([255, 78, 48, ..., 190, 230, 178], dtype=uint8)
```

l want to store that in matrix such that each line represents a vector (3072) of an image. which means l get at the end a matrix of (1000,3072)
here is what l tried

```
matrix_of_images= []
for img in images:
    data.append(img)
    data.append(img2)
```

however append list gives me a structure which is difficult to manipulate since l want to store it in csv file then call a part of an image.

```
[array([255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8), array([255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8), array([255, 255, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0], dtype=uint8), array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8), array([255, 255, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0], dtype=uint8), array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8), array([255, 255, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0], dtype=uint8), array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)]
```

l'm looking for something like 
X=

```
[

[23,56, 78,....,45,156],
[60,56, 104,....,145,157],
[78,45, 7,....,0,15],
[45,56, 178,....,5,200]

]
```

where l can read form example

```
X[1] #  second image
 [60,56, 104,....,145,157]
X[1][2] # third pixel of second image
104
```

a structure which is easy to store in csv file  where each pixel in a column.

**EDIT :**
the vectors to add at each iteration are `img1` and `img2`

```
for i in range(1,500):

    #get coordinates
    #coords=npa[i,:]
    coords=npa.iloc[[i]]
    charac=characs[i-1]
    if (charac== "'/'"):
        charac= "'slash'"

    charac = charac.strip('"\'')
    #actual cropping of the image (easy with numpy)
    #img_charac=img[int(coords[2]):int(coords[4]),int(coords[3]):int(coords[5])]
    img_charac = img[int(coords[4]):int(coords[5]), int(coords[2]):int(coords[3])]
    #cv2.imwrite(path_save_cropped_images + str(charac) + "_" + str(i) + "_" + str(img_charac.shape) + ".png",  img_charac)

    #resize
    img_charac_resized=cv2.resize(img_charac, (32, 32), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    #cv2.imwrite(path_save_resized_images + str(charac) + "_" + str(i) + "_" + str(img_charac_resized.shape) + ".png",img_charac_resized)
    #img_charac = cv2.resize(img_charac, (32, 32))

    #switch images
    img_charac_switched = 255 - img_charac_resized
    #cv2.imwrite(path_save_switched_pixels+ str(charac) +"_switched"+ "_" + str(i) + "_" + str(img_charac_switched.shape) + ".png",img_charac_switched)

    img1 = img_charac_resized.reshape((-1, 1))
    img1 = img1.T
    img1= img1.flatten()
    img1_label=charac

    img2=img_charac_switched.reshape((-1,1))
    img2=img2.T
    img2=img2.flatten()
    img2_label = charac
    #x=switch(charac)
    #saving the image

    #dataset

    #cv2.imwrite(path_dataset+ str(charac) + "_switched" + "_" + str(i) + "_" + str(img_charac_switched.shape) + ".png",img_charac_switched)
    #cv2.imwrite(path_dataset + str(charac) + "_" + str(i) + "_" + str(img_charac_resized.shape) + ".png",  img_charac_resized)


    #images = [img1,img2]
    img_arr = np.stack(img1, axis=0)
    img_arr = np.stack(img2, axis=0)
    #data.append(img1)
    #data.append(img2)

    #print (img_arr.shape)
    #print(i)



print(img_arr)
print(img_arr.shape)
```

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your changes. In the future, please make sure the question fully reflects the problems you are facing, and that the code is complete. For example, you did not state clearly that you were trying to append two lists at once, nor did you clearly define what the variables `images` or `data` were. Nevertheless, I hope you found my answer useful, as using `numpy.stack` instead of `append` addressed the root problem you needed to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using `numpy.stack`. Specify `axis=0` to stack vertically:

```
import numpy as np
n = 1000
images = [np.random.random(3072) for _ in range(n)]
img_arr = np.stack(images,axis=0)

>>> img_arr.shape
(1000, 3072)
```

In the case of your code:

```
images = []
for i in range(500):
    # create img1 and img2
    images.extend([img1,img2])
img_arr = np.stack(images,axis=0)
```

Comment: l need to be inside the for loop in my code l have img1 and img2 to add sequentially to my numpy.stack

Comment: at each for loop iteration l add img1 and img2 sequentially. Which means that after each loop iteration my img_arr will be increased by two until it reached 1000 at the end of for loop. hope it's more clear

Comment: no, it's not clear. you already have a list of `np.array` objects in `images`. All you have to do is stack the list you already have.

Comment: please see my update l shared the block of code where l extract at each iteration two sub-images : img1 and img2 . At each for loop iteration l add the vectors of img1 and img2 to my stack list which means at the end of each 1 one for loop iteration my  numpy. stack will be increased by 2 and at the end of my for loop l get the shape (1000,3072) but in each iteration it increases by (2,3072)

Answer (score 0):

```
images=[]

for i in range(1,500):




    img1= img1.flatten()


    img2=img2.flatten()
    #saving the image

    images.append(img1)
    images.append(img2)


img_arr = np.stack(images, axis=0)
print(len(images))
print(img_arr)
print(img_arr.shape)
```